# linker option to list libraries used

Tags: c++, build, linker

I am working on a Linux platform and using the GNU C++ compiler.  I am trying to resolve a link error that says some symbols are undefined.  I can go find libraries with the name provided on the command line, and see that they contain the symbols in question ( using the 'nm' utility ).

I know that for the compilation step, I can use the command-line flag '-H' instead of '-c' in order to get a list of header files that were #included into the compilation.  Is there a similar option for the linker?  I figure if I could see the list of files that the linker used to handle each '-lmylibrary' flag, I can troubleshoot further.

Comment: While not a compile time flag, `ldd` is a very useful linux utility to run on actual compiled applications/libraries.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you get an undefined symbol error it means you forgot to link some library, knowing which libraries you link to will probably not be as useful as you may think, because obviously the symbol is missing from those libraries, however you can use the `-print-file-name=library` option to find out which path gcc would use to link a library, example:

```
$ gcc -print-file-name=libc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../libc.a
```

Also passing `--trace` to the linker shows a similar output

```
gcc -Wl,--trace myprog.c -o myprog -L. -lmylib
-lmylib (./libmylib.a)
-lgcc_s (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.5.2/libgcc_s.so)
....
```

(Note in the above that `--trace` is *an argument to the linker* so it goes in `-Wl`. `gcc` invoked for linking won't emit anything useful for `--trace` as an argument to `gcc` its self).

You could also use `ldd` *after* you successfully build the program to find out which dynamically linked libraries were used, its output looks like this:

```
ldd `which ls`
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7ffff000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f2e8ea93000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2e8e88b000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f2e8e682000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e8e2ee000)
....
```

Comment: The question doesn't ask for an option to "list missing libraries," it asks for an option to "list full paths of libraries used to satisfy -l options."

Comment: answering another question: -1

Comment: The --print-file-name is close; it looks like that works only for libraries that are on GCC's built-in paths, such as /usr/lib/.  The --trace gives me the output I'm looking for here so I'll accept this.

Comment: @Sesquipedalian you can add other linker options with `--print-file-name` like `-L.` or `-L./lib` to search for your libraries.

Comment: @mux that didn't seem to work on my g++; it just prints the name that I passed to --print-file-name without resolving the absolute path.

Comment: @Sesquipedalian you need to pass the full library file name, for example `libmylib.a`

Comment: @mux Yep.  `g++ -L/vobs/bldd_libs/sol_d --print-file-name=libhmiexecution.a `  gives me `libhmiexecution.a`.  I did an `ls` to make sure the library is actually there.

Comment: @Sesquipedalian strange looks like it doesn't work for user libraries, anyway, at least you have the `--trace` option :)

Comment: The interface to `-print-file-name` is weird, it prints the input in case it is not found: `-print-file-name=asdfqwer`. It seems that it only checks if the search path exists, no the actual file.