# How to see which static libraries were used for gcc/g++ compilation from the generated binary?

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, g++, static-libraries, cross-compiling

Context: I'm using a linux toolchain (includes `g++`, other build tools, libs, headers, etc) to build my code with statically linked libraries. I want to ensure that I'm using ONLY libraries/headers from my toolchain, not the default ones on the build machine. I can use `strace` to see what g++ is doing (which libraries it is using) while it is compiling which *would* be helpful in a normal scenario - but my build system has many wrappers around g++ that hide all of the output.

Question: is there a way to obtain from a statically-linked binary any useful information regarding the library and header files which were used to create the binary? I've taken a look at the `objdump` tool but I'm not sure if it will help much.

Comment: A "while compiling" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735387/linker-option-to-list-libraries-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can simply recompile, then there are ways (using some of the techniques that Basile explained) to get the headers and libraries (static or dynamic) but, unfortunately, there is no way to know which libraries were used after the compilation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass `-v` to `g++` or `gcc` at link time. It will show all the linked libraries. Perhaps try `make CC='gcc -v' CXX='g++ -v'`

More generally, `-v` passed `g++` or `gcc` shows you the underlying command with its arguments because `gcc` or `g++` is just a driver program (starting `cc1`, `ld` or `collect2`, `as`, ...)

By passing the `-H` flag to GCC (i.e. `g++` or `gcc`) you can see every included header. So you can check that only the heanders you expect are included.

You cannot see what static library has been linked, because linking a static library just means linking the relevant object file members in it, so a static library can (and usually is) linked in only partly.

You could use the `nm` command to find names from such libraries.